# Outlook 2007 contact item context menu

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I want to customize contact context menu, I know that I have to do it using `CommandBars` approach. [This approach is NOT very useful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.itemcontextmenudisplay%28v=office.12%29.aspx). How can I add two buttons programmatically when I click a contact item and handle the click event.

I want add my personalized CALL (TAPI) and Journal (TAPI) with each event. How can I retrieve data of contact when I've clicked on one button?

I need this for today max tomorrow. I need this for my work project....and I have only one week. I would like to gladly a lot of examples but they should be examples that I can copy and modify them according to my needs. I asked on MSDN forum, a real disappointment nobody answered, and I plugged in my black list of useless forum. So I would like someone to give me an answer.

If anything in return I'll explain how you make a call from Outlook or any other application in c# using the library created by **Atapi Julmar**. For those interested, I created a bar on the desktop is hidden and from which you can make internal calls to employees using the phone **innovaphone + tapi**. So if you have any information I will give you in return my otherwise you'll go away from my topic.

Comment: ??? what? I've writed Hello everyone!  And so i will not get any help :(

Comment: Please read the [faq]. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Readed. I want an answer for it and not for these stupide sentences.

Comment: It's not a huge problem, but just stick to the question, and don't write as though you were having a polite conversation.